# bitcoin core node cannot route to peers

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, peers

I'm trying to sync a new full node in the cloud, however it's syncing a lot slower than I am used to: I am roughly at 70,000 blocks after about 12 hours.

- It doesn't seem to be slow IO, `iotop` shows that everything is idle and almost nothing is being written.
- My node is making connections: according to `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo` I should have 10 active connections right now.
- There has been almost no network traffic, less than 100mb over the last 12 hours.

But this is what my `debug.log` shows:

```
~/.bitcoin# tail -n 100 debug.log 
2018-01-26 10:07:07 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:09 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:10 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:10 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:12 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:13 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:15 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:16 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:18 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:19 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:21 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:22 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:24 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:25 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:27 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:28 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:30 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:31 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:33 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:34 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:36 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:37 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:39 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:40 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:42 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:43 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:45 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:47 receive version message: /breadwallet:0.6.2/: version 70013, blocks=0, us=[redacted]:8333, peer=885
2018-01-26 10:07:52 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:52 receive version message: /breadwallet:0.6.2/: version 70013, blocks=0, us=[redacted]:8333, peer=886
2018-01-26 10:07:53 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:55 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:56 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:57 receive version message: /Snoopy:0.2.1/: version 70001, blocks=0, us=[redacted]:8333, peer=887
2018-01-26 10:07:58 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:07:59 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:01 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:02 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:04 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:05 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:07 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:08 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:10 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:11 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:13 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:15 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:16 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:18 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:19 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:21 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:22 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:24 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:25 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:27 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:28 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:30 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:37 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:38 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:40 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:41 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:43 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:50 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:51 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:53 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:54 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:56 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:57 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:08:59 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:00 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:02 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:09 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:10 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:12 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:13 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:13 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:15 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:17 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:18 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:20 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:21 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:23 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:24 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:26 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:27 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:29 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:30 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:32 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:33 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:35 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:36 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:38 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:39 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:41 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:42 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:44 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:45 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:47 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:48 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:50 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
2018-01-26 10:09:57 connect() to [redacted]:8333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
```

I've redacted the IP addresses, but all of them are unreachable from my vps box, whereas I can reach them fine outside of the box (making this not a bitcoin core problem but a networking problem).

---

EDIT:

As requested more debug output:

> the VPS host, can you try >telnet redacted 8333

Output:

```
~/.bitcoin# telnet [redacted]:8333
telnet: could not resolve [redacted]:8333/telnet: Name or service not known
```

And:

```
~/.bitcoin# nmap [redacted] -p8333

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-26 08:13 EST
Nmap scan report for [redacted] ([redacted])
Host is up (0.0069s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8333/tcp filtered bitcoin

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.42 seconds
```

Which is strange: nmap works but nothing else seems to be able to route.

I am not using Tor nor have I configured any bitcoin.conf file. Everything is default and I downloaded the default linux build (0.15.1) from bitcoincore.org (checksum matched).

> Also, check which interfaces the bitcoin node is bound to especially if your VPS has multiple net interfaces.

It only has one called `venet0` and one called `venet0:0` (latter has the IP public bound). I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Here is the first 150 lines of the debug.log (when bitcoind was first started): https://gist.github.com/askmike/5ae06e6ffec122e8634df97e9dae4cf5

EDIT2:

It turned out to be a firewall problem from my VPS provider.

Comment: Okay, nmap worked. telnet probably only didn't work because you have a : between the IP and the port, just leave a space. So the VPS can rout to a node. Probably just leaves Bitcoin Core. Are you running bitcoin-qt or bitcoind (and, is it running as a daemon?)? If you run `>route -v -n` how many destinations of 0.0.0.0 do you have in the left hand column with different iface values in the right hand column? Also, there *may* be a permission error since you have a few entries like `Invalid or missing banlist.dat; recreating`

Comment: What do you get if you run the command with Bitcoin Core running: `>ps -eo user,group,comm |egrep 'bitcoind|bitcoin-qt' |awk '{print "Bitcoin user: " $1}'` and does it give you the user you login as?

Comment: 1. I'm only running bitcoind as a deamon. 2. telnetting doesn't work after adjusting the command (now it errors with `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`). 3. I think the banlist issue was just a message on first run (bitcoin datadir was empty so it had to create everything).  4. yes it does give me the user I logged in as.

Comment: I created a support ticket with the webhost, to me it sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: It is fairly routine to get no route to host when connecting to IPv6 addresses (it is common enough for web hosts and segments of some ISP networks not to route v6) but I presume not all of the fail entries in your logs are IPv6. What about the route command? I am being presumptuous that your VPS is trying to route on the local interface that has no upstream routing to the intenet. A ticket with your host may help you solve this easily regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines like this mean you are actually connecting to some nodes:

```
2018-01-26 10:07:57 receive version message: /Snoopy:0.2.1/: version 70001, blocks=0, us=[redacted]:8333, peer=887
```

But it impossible for me to tell from what you have posted if that peer is later one that is failing, I do not think so.

In the VPS host, can you try `>telnet redacted 8333` or `>nmap redacted -p8333` or `>traceroute redacted -p 8333` and add it to your question?

btw: if you want a tool to do node checking apparently this works: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=760565.msg13820110#msg13820110

Also, check which interfaces the bitcoin node is bound to especially if your VPS has multiple net interfaces. It should show up in the `debug.log` shortly after node restart.

There are some options like `-onlynet=` that can cause connectivity issues, what is in your config file or on your command line used to start the node?

Are you using tor?

It could just be a smart firewall or web filter issue with your VPS host.

Comment: Added more debug information to the question!

Comment: @askmike when you get this sorted, I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer if it helped you, so as to not leave the question "unanswered" -- I am happy to edit my answer further if it is needed.

Comment: I will! It looks like a firewall issue (your last sentence) and once I know this for sure I will comment and accept.

Comment: it was indeed a firewall problem from the VPS provider. It has now been fixed :)